# Getting java error while invoking new PayPalPaymentDetails() from javascript in cordova android app

Tags: java, android, cordova, paypal

I followed the steps mentioned in https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin.

Added the content of https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/tree/master/libs to my projects libs folder.
And successfully done a build.

When I clicked on a payment button, the following errors showed up in the logCat console of eclipse

```
11-22 20:32:54.778: I/dalvikvm(9132): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable, referenced from method com.paypal.android.sdk.bs.a
11-22 20:32:54.778: W/dalvikvm(9132): VFY: unable to resolve static method 692: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable (Landroid/content/Context;)I
11-22 20:32:54.778: D/dalvikvm(9132): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0006
11-22 20:32:54.798: D/AndroidRuntime(9132): Shutting down VM
11-22 20:32:54.798: W/dalvikvm(9132): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4157dba8)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132): Process: com.hello.app, PID: 9132
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind to service com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService@41fd4068 with Intent { cmp=com.hello.app/com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: Service extras required. Please see the docs.
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:2597)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Service extras required. Please see the docs.
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.a(Unknown Source)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PayPalService.onBind(Unknown Source)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:2584)
11-22 20:32:54.798: E/AndroidRuntime(9132):     ... 10 more
11-22 20:32:54.869: D/dalvikvm(9132): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 725K, 26% free 10873K/14600K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
11-22 20:32:54.989: D/dalvikvm(9132): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 499K, 25% free 11004K/14600K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
11-22 20:32:56.180: D/dalvikvm(9132): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 641K, 25% free 11039K/14600K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
```

I am using PayPalAndroidSDK-2.7.1.
Note: The integration for iOS cordova app worked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

These errors come when we don't do PayPalMobile.init(), which I had missed. Now everything works perfectly.